# How can i request an api faster in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Im making a project that calculates nutritional values in a recipe just by ingridient name and values, i found a API that helps with that but the code to request is really slow.

```
def get_nutrition(food: str) -> dict:
    
    with open("apikey.txt", "r") as f:
        key = f.read().strip()
    api_url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/nutrition?query={}'.format(food)
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers={'X-Api-Key': key})
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        return json.loads(response.text)
        
    else:
        return "Error:", response.status_code, response.text
```

I tried to do the api call in javascript in a async function so the page at leasts loads and the nutritional value is filled out later, but i came to the issue that i cant easily hide the API key, even heard its impossible.

Is there any way i can either do the request faster or hide the API key to use in javascript?

EDIT : i got the load time down from 2ish seconds to 0.7 seconds by doing one api call for all ingridients rather than one for each, but i would still like to get it to around 0.3-0.5 if possible

Comment: There is no "make it faster" command in Python or any other language.  When you measure the performance, what specifically is the bottleneck?

Comment: the page takes too long to load because the api call is pretty slow. By making it faster i meant if there is a more efficient way to do it or do it async or or do it in a different thread.

Comment: If the network connection and/or the destination server itself is slow then I don't see how *code changes* would make it faster.

Comment: On the client side you should still be requesting get_nutrition asynchronously

Comment: there must be a way right? is there a way i can do the api call asynchrony in python and redirect when its ready?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that flask uses a separate thread for each request so blocking shouldn't be an issue. Does your page freeze when you request the data?

Comment: the page just loads like ~2 seconds slower than any other page that has just a db call

Comment: Async doesn't make anything faster.  It just lets you do other things while you wait.  If you don't have anything else to do, then it is pointless.  It is POSSIBLE they do bandwidth limiting to avoid having people swamp their free service.

Comment: You might build a cache - so that popular food list results are written to some cache, and then if the same food list is requested again the response can be read from the cache instead of a fresh api request.  You could run a script to pre-populate it.

Comment: ive thought of doing that for saving money/api calls rather than speed. I will implement it and get back to you.